Power Query merged table returns pre-sorted values
I have two tables that I need to merge using an ID column.
Both of then have duplicated values, but I only need the max values.
So, I sorted the tables in descending order and removed the duplicates.
However, after merging the tables, instead of receiving the max value, the merged table returns the first value before sorting.
The tables are like this:



ID
value1




a
8.7


a
10.9


b
5.2


c
9.0






ID
value2




a
50


b
60


c
80



I sorted the tables and removed the duplicates:



ID
value1




a
10.9


b
5.2


c
9.0






ID
value2




a
50


b
60


c
80



After the merge, I get this:



ID
value1
value2




a
8.7
50


b
5.2
60


c
9.0
80



But I want this:



ID
value1
value2




a
10.9
50


b
5.2
60


c
9.0
80



This is how my code looks like:
#first table to be merged
let
    source = Table.Combine({table1, table2}),
    sorted = Table.Sort(source,{{"value1", Order.Descending}}),
    remove_duplicates = Table.Distinct(sorted, {"ID"}),
    table1_final = Table.Sort(remove_duplicates ,{{"ID", Order.Ascending}})

#second table to be merged
    source2 = Table.Combine({table1, table2}),
    sorted2 = Table.Sort(source2,{{"value2", Order.Descending}}),
    remove_duplicates2 = Table.Distinct(sorted2, {"ID"}),
    table2_final = Table.Sort(remove_duplicates ,{{"ID", Order.Ascending}})

#merged table    
    source3 = Table.NestedJoin(table1_final, {"ID"}, table2_final , {"ID"}, "table1_final ", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(source3 , "table2_final", {"value2"}, {"value2"})

in
    expanded


Take the first table. Group it to get maximums

Merge the second table. Expand value2 column

Full code
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"value1", each List.Max([value1]), type nullable number}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Grouped Rows", {"ID"}, Table2, {"ID"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"value2"}, {"value2"})
in #"Expanded Table2"


It solved my problem, thanks!
I'm new to power query, do you know how to explain why this happens?

What I added here was a simplifyied version of the actual code.
I still can't understand why the filtered version of the table would not be enough for the merge to work.
